# MySQL: obtain primary key value generated by before-insert trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, primary-key, last-insert-id

In MySQL, is there any way to obtain a primary key value generated by a before-insert trigger?

I know that `select last_insert_id()` can return the first value of an `auto_increment` column from a previous insert, but I can't seem to get it to work with a trigger-generated primary key.

There is no other unique key on my table, so I won't be able to perform a subsequent select to determine the generated primary key by just using data that was used in the insert.

Comment: you have to use an "after insert" trigger - the id value won't be available until the new record hits storage.

Comment: I'm trying to get the value that was generated in my before-insert trigger to the calling client, which is a Java JDBC client.  I don't see how an after-insert trigger will help me.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I have a similar issue as well.